# connecting javaprogram to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

```
String dburl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librarymanagementsystem";
String user = "nandika";
String password = "nandika";

public void createConnection(int id, String name, String author, String 
    publisher) {
    try {
        Connection mycon = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl);
        Statement mystmt = mycon.createStatement();
        String sql = "insert into addbook" + "(Book ID,Book 
        Name,Author,Publisher)" + "values" + "(" + id + "," + name + "," + 
        author + "," + publisher + ")";

        mystmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("updated");
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
```

execute update is a method in another class.there seem to be 
whats the wrong with this code segment? database is not updating!!

Comment: Does it print `updated`? What does the Exception say (which you ignored)?

Comment: Did you import drivers?

Comment: you seem to be missing spaces in your sql & always remember to use prepared statements

Comment: You've also got a string literal split over two lines. I don't think this will compile.

Comment: not related but worth pointing it out, be careful with this sort of query, make sure the input is safe otherwise you might get a injection issue there, especially if this is for a website. prefer prepared statements.

Comment: Remove your empty `catch` block and see what exceptions you're ignoring.

Comment: I posted an short answer, got some negative votes and deleted it. The point was that you're never using **user** and **password** in your code.

Comment: @zlakad is right.. Next time change `catch (Exception ex) {

    }`  into `catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }`  then you get a beter error message.. For more usefull error messages in the future..

Answer (score 6):

You have not loaded the database drivers, to do that include this code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

If you haven't drivers download and put in project library.

Answer (score 2):

Their are some problems with this code snippet. One is you **didn't load the database**. Also you **didn't use the username and password**.

I recommend you to create the database connection separately. Maybe in a separate Java file. As below,

```
public class DatabaseConnection {
    public static Statement getConnection() throws Exception{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //Loading the database
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/restaurentsystem","nandika","nandika"); //username and password can save as variables and pass here

        Statement statement = c.createStatement();
        return statement;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it whenever you want. In this situation,

```
try {
    Statement s = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
    s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO addbook (Book ID, Book Name, Author, Publisher) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);"); //Values should assign here.
    System.out.println("updated");

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

This is what I do if I do this. I recommend you to try this method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you should be doing it, with preparedStatement to prevent injections

```
String dburl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librarymanagementsystem";
String user = "nandika";
String password = "nandika";
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
private Connection con = null;


      public static void main(String[] args) {

}


public void createConnection(int id, String name, String author, String publisher) {
    try {




con = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, user, password);
String stmt = "INSERT INTO addbook (Book ID,Book Name,Author,Publisher) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";



            preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(stmt);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, name);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, author);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, publisher);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            con.close();

        System.out.println("updated");
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
```